# The script runs fine on localhost but fails on Server

Tags: javascript, php, html, data-binding, canvasjs

I have this html file (.html on local and .php for server) and respective js code. when I developed, It ran fine on local machine. As soon as I uploaded it on the server it failed to run in the same way. To be specific only the jquery function is working and not the onclick function (as per my debug report).

Also, when I run the file locally on my Ubuntu it runs fine but fails to run locally on a windows machine.

More on above, **eventually I figured out it works on forefox but not on chrome. so no relation to os.**

console error on live web

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'stayondiscount.com/dynamicprice/nodal.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'stayondiscount.com/favicon.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="nodal.js"></script>

            <title>Revenue Management System for Hotels</title>

            <style>
                .box{
                    color: #fff;
                    padding: 20px;
                    display: none;
                    margin-top: 20px;
                }
            </style>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Choose City</option>
                        <option value="gurgaon" onclick="openCity(event, 'Gurgaon')">Gurgaon</option>
                        <option value="delhi" onclick="openCity(event, 'Delhi')">Delhi</option>
                        <option value="noida" onclick="openCity(event, 'Noida')">Noida</option>
                        <option value="jaipur" onclick="openCity(event, 'Jaipur')">Jaipur</option>
                        <option value="kolkata" onclick="openCity(event, 'Kolkata')">Kolkata</option>
                        <option value="bangalore" onclick="openCity(event, 'Bangalore')">Bangalore</option>
                        <option value="chennai" onclick="openCity(event, 'Chennai')">Chennai</option>
                        <option value="pune" onclick="openCity(event, 'Pune')">Pune</option>
                        <option value="mumbai" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mumbai')">Mumbai</option>
                        <option value="goa" onclick="openCity(event, 'Goa')">Goa</option>

                    </select>
                </div>


                <div class="gurgaon box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart1" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile1" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="delhi box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart2" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile2" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="noida box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart3" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile3" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="jaipur box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart4" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile4" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="kolkata box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart5" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile5" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="bangalore box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart6" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile6" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="chennai box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart7" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile7" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="pune box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart8" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile8" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="mumbai box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart9" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile9" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

                <div class="goa box">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="chart10" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="col-sm-6" id="percentile10" style="height: 500px;"></div>

                     </div>

                </div>

            </div>


            <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
        </body>

    </html>
```

--------this is the js file----------------------------

```
var bangalore = [];
var bangalore_avg = [];
var bangalore_tenth_percentile = [];
var bangalore_nintyth_percentile = [];

var chennai = [];
var chennai_avg = [];
var chennai_tenth_percentile = [];
var chennai_nintyth_percentile = [];

var pune = [];
var pune_avg = [];
var pune_tenth_percentile = [];
var pune_nintyth_percentile = [];

var mumbai = [];
var mumbai_avg = [];
var mumbai_tenth_percentile = [];
var mumbai_nintyth_percentile = [];

var goa = [];
var goa_avg = [];
var goa_tenth_percentile = [];
var goa_nintyth_percentile = [];

var kolkata = [];
var kolkata_avg = [];
var kolkata_tenth_percentile = [];
var kolkata_nintyth_percentile = [];
var jaipur = [];
var jaipur_avg = [];
var jaipur_tenth_percentile = [];
var jaipur_nintyth_percentile = [];

var noida = [];
var noida_avg = [];
var noida_tenth_percentile = [];
var noida_nintyth_percentile = [];

var delhi = [];
var delhi_avg = [];
var delhi_tenth_percentile = [];
var delhi_nintyth_percentile = [];

var gurgaon = [];
var gurgaon_avg = [];
var gurgaon_tenth_percentile = [];
var gurgaon_nintyth_percentile = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("select").change(function(){

        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){

            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");

            if(optionValue){

                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();

            } 
            else{

                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});

    function openCity(evt, cityName) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = "GET",
        url = "https://api.nodal.direct/v1/index.php/Api/getNodalGraph";
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

                var api_data = xhr.responseText;
                var api_json = JSON.parse(api_data); 
                var data = api_json["data"];

                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

                    iter_data = data[i];
                    data_region = iter_data["region"];
                    data_median = iter_data["median_price"];
                    data_avg = iter_data["avg_price"];
                    data_date = iter_data["date"];
                    data_tenth_percentile = iter_data["tenth_percentile"];
                    data_nintyth_percentile = iter_data["ninty_percentile"];

                    var datearray = data_date.split("-");
                    var newdate = datearray[0] + ', ' + datearray[1] + ', ' + datearray[2];

                    if(data_region == "gurgaon") {
                        gurgaon.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        gurgaon_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        gurgaon_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        gurgaon_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "delhi") {
                        delhi.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        delhi_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        delhi_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        delhi_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "noida") {
                        noida.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        noida_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        noida_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        noida_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "jaipur") {
                        jaipur.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        jaipur_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        jaipur_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        jaipur_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "kolkata") {
                        kolkata.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        kolkata_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        kolkata_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        kolkata_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "bangalore") {
                        bangalore.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        bangalore_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        bangalore_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        bangalore_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }

                    else if(data_region == "chennai") {
                        chennai.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        chennai_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        chennai_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        chennai_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "pune") {
                        pune.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        pune_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        pune_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        pune_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "mumbai") {
                        mumbai.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        mumbai_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        mumbai_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        mumbai_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }
                    else if(data_region == "goa") {
                        goa.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_median)});
                        goa_avg.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_avg)});
                        goa_tenth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_tenth_percentile)});
                        goa_nintyth_percentile.push({x:new Date(newdate), y:Number(data_nintyth_percentile)});
                    }

                    else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                var city = cityName.toString();

                if(city == "Gurgaon") {

                    var _name_ = "Gurgaon";
                    var active = 1;
                    data_array = gurgaon.slice(gurgaon.length - 4, gurgaon.length);
                    avg_array = gurgaon_avg.slice(gurgaon_avg.length - 4, gurgaon_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = gurgaon_tenth_percentile.slice(gurgaon_tenth_percentile.length - 4, gurgaon_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = gurgaon_nintyth_percentile.slice(gurgaon_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, gurgaon_nintyth_percentile.length);
                    console.log(nintyth_array);
                }

                else if(city == "Delhi") {

                    var _name_ = "Delhi";   
                    var active = 2;
                    data_array = delhi.slice(delhi.length - 4, delhi.length);
                    avg_array = delhi_avg.slice(delhi_avg.length - 4, delhi_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = delhi_tenth_percentile.slice(delhi_tenth_percentile.length - 4, delhi_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = delhi_nintyth_percentile.slice(delhi_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, delhi_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }

                else if(city == "Noida") {

                    var _name_ = "Noida";
                    var active = 3;
                    data_array = noida.slice(noida.length - 4, noida.length);
                    avg_array = noida_avg.slice(noida_avg.length - 4, noida_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = noida_tenth_percentile.slice(noida_tenth_percentile.length - 4, noida_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = noida_nintyth_percentile.slice(noida_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, noida_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }

                else if(city == "Jaipur") {

                    var _name_ = "Jaipur";
                    var active = 4;
                    data_array = jaipur.slice(jaipur.length - 4, jaipur.length);
                    avg_array = jaipur_avg.slice(jaipur_avg.length - 4, jaipur_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = jaipur_tenth_percentile.slice(jaipur_tenth_percentile.length - 4, jaipur_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = jaipur_nintyth_percentile.slice(jaipur_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, jaipur_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }

                else if(city == "Kolkata") {

                    var _name_ = "Kolkata";
                    var active = 5;
                    data_array = kolkata.slice(kolkata.length - 4, kolkata.length);
                    avg_array = kolkata_avg.slice(kolkata_avg.length - 4, kolkata_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = kolkata_tenth_percentile.slice(kolkata_tenth_percentile.length - 4, kolkata_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = kolkata_nintyth_percentile.slice(kolkata_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, kolkata_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }
                else if(city == "Bangalore") {

                    var _name_ = "Bangalore";
                    var active = 6;
                    data_array = bangalore.slice(bangalore.length - 4, bangalore.length);
                    avg_array = bangalore_avg.slice(bangalore_avg.length - 4, bangalore_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = bangalore_tenth_percentile.slice(bangalore_tenth_percentile.length - 4, bangalore_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = bangalore_nintyth_percentile.slice(bangalore_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, bangalore_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }
                else if(city == "Chennai") {

                    var _name_ = "Chennai";
                    var active = 7;
                    data_array = chennai.slice(chennai.length - 4, chennai.length);
                    avg_array = chennai_avg.slice(chennai_avg.length - 4, chennai_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = chennai_tenth_percentile.slice(chennai_tenth_percentile.length - 4, chennai_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = chennai_nintyth_percentile.slice(chennai_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, chennai_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }
                else if(city == "Pune") {

                    var _name_ = "Pune";
                    var active = 8;
                    data_array = pune.slice(pune.length - 4, pune.length);
                    avg_array = pune_avg.slice(pune_avg.length - 4, pune_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = pune_tenth_percentile.slice(pune_tenth_percentile.length - 4, pune_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = pune_nintyth_percentile.slice(pune_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, pune_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }
                else if(city == "Mumbai") {

                    var _name_ = "Mumbai";
                    var active = 9;
                    data_array = mumbai.slice(mumbai.length - 4, mumbai.length);
                    avg_array = mumbai_avg.slice(mumbai_avg.length - 4, mumbai_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = mumbai_tenth_percentile.slice(mumbai_tenth_percentile.length - 4, mumbai_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = mumbai_nintyth_percentile.slice(mumbai_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, mumbai_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }

                else if(city == "Goa") {

                    var _name_ = "Goa";
                    var active = 10;
                    data_array = goa.slice(goa.length - 4, goa.length);
                    avg_array = goa_avg.slice(goa_avg.length - 4, goa_avg.length);
                    tenth_array = goa_tenth_percentile.slice(goa_tenth_percentile.length - 4, goa_tenth_percentile.length);
                    nintyth_array = goa_nintyth_percentile.slice(goa_nintyth_percentile.length - 4, goa_nintyth_percentile.length);
                }

                else {
                    console.log("test it");
                }

                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart" + active, {

                    title: {
                        text: _name_ + " Market Prices",
                        fontSize: 15,
                    },
                    axisX: {
                        valueFormatString: "DD-MM-YY",
                        labelFontSize: 10,
                    },
                    axisY2: {
                        title: "Price",
                        interval: 700,
                        titleFontSize: 15,
                        labelFontSize: 10,
                        prefix: "â‚¹ ",
                        suffix: " "
                    },
                    toolTip: {
                        shared: true
                    },
                    legend: {
                        cursor: "pointer",
                        fontSize: 10,
                        verticalAlign: "top",
                        horizontalAlign: "center",
                        dockInsidePlotArea: true,
                        itemclick: toogleDataSeries
                    },
                    data:[
                        {
                          type:"line",
                          axisYType: "secondary",
                          name: "Median Price",
                          showInLegend: true,
                          markerSize: 1,
                          yValueFormatString: "#,###",
                          dataPoints: data_array

                        },
                        {
                        type:"line",
                        axisYType: "secondary",
                        name: "Average Price",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        markerSize: 1,
                        yValueFormatString: "#,###",
                        dataPoints: avg_array
                        }
                    ]
                });

                chart.render();

                function toogleDataSeries(e) {

                  if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                  } 
                  else {
                        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                    }

                    chart.render();
                }

                var percentile = new CanvasJS.Chart("percentile" + active, {

                    title: {
                        text: _name_ + " Median Price Percentile",
                        fontSize: 15,
                    },
                    axisX: {
                        valueFormatString: "DD-MM-YY",
                        labelFontSize: 10,
                    },
                    axisY2: {
                        title: "Percentile",
                        interval: 700,
                        titleFontSize: 15,
                        labelFontSize: 10,
                        prefix: "â‚¹ ",
                        suffix: " "
                    },
                    toolTip: {
                        shared: true
                    },
                    legend: {
                        cursor: "pointer",
                        fontSize: 10,
                        verticalAlign: "top",
                        horizontalAlign: "center",
                        dockInsidePlotArea: true,
                        itemclick: toogleDataSeries
                    },
                    data:[
                      {
                        type:"line",
                        axisYType: "secondary",
                        name: "10th Percentile",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        markerSize: 1,
                        yValueFormatString: "#,###",
                        dataPoints: tenth_array
                      },
                      {
                        type:"line",
                        axisYType: "secondary",
                        name: "90th Percentile",
                        showInLegend: true,
                        markerSize: 1,
                        yValueFormatString: "#,###",
                        dataPoints: nintyth_array
                      }
                    ]
                });

                percentile.render();
                function toogleDataSeries(e) {

                    if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                    } 
                    else {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                        }
                    percentile.render();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "as per my debug report" - what is your debug report?

Comment: You're most probably not referencing the correct file path for your `nodal.js` file.

Comment: @JaromandaX like when I tested the functionality.

Comment: @AndrewL64 nodal.js is in same folder as nodal.html or nodal.php

Comment: check for errors in the browser developer console

Comment: @JaromandaX I did. Thats what the report about. Also one more thing is, that when I run onto my ubuntu system it runs fine but not on windows.

Comment: What webserver are you using? You could try to read in log files, maybe it's having a hard time delivering the file because permission or something.

Comment: @Marco WHM only. Also, I have run similar files before and they worked fine but this one is giving me a hard time.

Comment: WHM it's just a name for a virtual machine on some hosting. They use a webserver to deliver your files, for sure. Try to call your-host + /nodal.js and see what kind of response do you get.

Comment: @Marco I tried that too. I hosted my js file on the server and gave a url to that js in nodal.html but still not working.

Comment: I think you should post the errors in the browser developer console to this post as well.

Comment: @Jason I have no errors on console to post

Comment: give me your site link so that I can check or check the nodal.js file embedded in document correctly.

Comment: @Manikandan This is the error on console when live................ nodal.php:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stayondiscount.com/dynamicprice/nodal.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://www.stayondiscount.com/favicon.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @Manikandan did you get the link? can you comment your observations?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>


try this in your .htaccess file it will fix the mixed content issue.

Comment: @Manikandan didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an `onclick` event listener on each option, try adding an `onchange` listener to the select field. 
You can do something like

```
<select onchange = "cityName(event)">
```

and then you can access the option like:

```
cityName(evt){
    city = evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value
}
```

`onclick` listener is not meant for option elements. It will fail in most browsers.
I tried fiddling with your script and changing the logic to `onchange` seems to work.

Comment: @Vivek Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/w48qa5td/30/  --

You were already using `onchange` event listener with jquery. I just called your function in the same listener.
Also, I would suggest moving out the ajax request from your function as you are just getting the same data on each call. The incoming data does not depend on the option selected I guess. The filtering out process can happen in a separate function

Comment: @Vivek also the frontend console error is because you are using `Http` protocol resources while loading an `https` page. Probably your page headers (and the favicon from your homepage) have links to scripts or static resources that have URL beginning with `http://` instead of `https://`